# How to use Read Lock in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My main procedure is spPet_TransferPettyCashToGL. From this procedure I'm calling (fnApp_GetCurrentBatchNo) function & get my **batch number** & use in the procedure for process. Before exit from the procedure I update my batch no.

I want to lock my `batch no` table & after update batch no I want to release this table.

Main SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPet_TransferPettyCashToGL] 
@ComCod as varchar(2),
@LocCod as varchar(2),
@PetDat as varchar(8)
AS
BEGIN
    /* Get New Batch No From Function */
    DECLARE @CurrentBatchNo as int
    EXECUTE @CurrentBatchNo = Accounts.dbo.fnApp_GetCurrentBatchNo @ComCode = @ComCod,
                                                               @LocCode = @LocCod

    /* Due to large code I ignored unnecessary areas. */

    /* UPDATE Provisional_Posting_Log  {Last Update Batch NO} */
    EXECUTE spApp_UpdateProvisionalPostingLogBatchNo @ComCod,
                                                     @LocCod,
                                                     @CurrentBatchNo
END
```

The function that gives `Batch No`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnApp_GetCurrentBatchNo] 
(
    @ComCode varchar(2),
    @LocCode varchar(2)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentBatchNo int

    SELECT @CurrentBatchNo = (SELECT (Last_Updated_Batch_No + 1)
                                 FROM Provisional_Posting_Log
                                      WHERE Company_Code = @ComCode AND
                                            Location_Code = @LocCode)

    RETURN @CurrentBatchNo
END
```

SP that updates `batch no` to the obtained value from FN above:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spApp_UpdateProvisionalPostingLogBatchNo]
    @ComCod as varchar(2),
    @LocCod as varchar(2),
    @CurrentBatchNo as int

AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Provisional_Posting_Log
           SET Last_Updated_Batch_No = CAST(@CurrentBatchNo as decimal(24,0))
               WHERE Company_Code = @ComCod AND
                     Location_Code = @LocCod
END
```

How can I lock `Provisional_Posting_Log` table when I getting batch no & how can I release it after Update batch no?

Comment: You will need update lock i.e table will be locked for update operation `with(updlock)`

Comment: Dear Ven, I'm using function to get my Batch_No. When exit from function is it lock release ?

Comment: Insert Begin and end for every process and perform Updlock for update operation, this should do the trick for you

Comment: What do you use that `@CurrentBatchNo` for? In the "processes".

Comment: Is there a reason you can't update the table when you get the new value? Anytime you do a roll your own increasing number like this it is fraught with challenges. Concurrency is the biggest issue but there are others. If you can get the new value and update it in your original function that alleviate a number of issues.